# В чем проблема? не записываться данные в setcookie!

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  //кодировка

    include("../bd.php");

    // получаем переменные через post
    $vkhod_lichnyynomer = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251", $_POST['vkhod_lichnyynomer']);
    $vkhod_password = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251", $_POST['vkhod_password']);

    // обрезаем пробелы
    $vkhod_lichnyynomer1 = trim($vkhod_lichnyynomer);
    $vkhod_password1 = trim($vkhod_password);

    // Экранируем опасные символы
    $vkhod_lichnyynomer2 = htmlspecialchars($vkhod_lichnyynomer1);
    $vkhod_password2 = htmlspecialchars($vkhod_password1);

    // Проверяем переменные на пустоту
    if($vkhod_lichnyynomer2 == '') {unset($vkhod_lichnyynomer2);}
    if($vkhod_password2 == '') {unset($vkhod_password2);}

    // Проверка заполненых данных
    if(isset($vkhod_lichnyynomer2) && isset($vkhod_password2)) {

        $users_test_login = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE lichnyynomer='$vkhod_lichnyynomer2'");
        $users_test_row = mysql_fetch_array($users_test_login);
        if($vkhod_lichnyynomer2 != $users_test_row['lichnyynomer']) {
            echo '<br><div id="bug" class="table_error"><span class="error_text_min"> Такого логина в нашей Базе нету!</span> <div style="clear:left;"></div></div><br>';
        }
        else {

            $users_test_pass = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE lichnyynomer='$vkhod_lichnyynomer2'");
            $password_users = mysql_fetch_array($users_test_pass);

        $vkhod_password_md = md5($vkhod_password2); // обязательно шифруем пароль.

        if($vkhod_password_md == $password_users['password']) {

            setcookie("lichnyynomer", $password_users['lichnyynomer'], time()+3600);
            setcookie("password", $password_users['password'], time()+3600); 

            echo '<br><div id="bug" class="table_ok"><span class="error_text_min"> Вход выполнен. Загружаем данные .... <img src="img/load.gif" width="15" height="15"></span> <div style="clear:left;"></div></div><br>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<br><div id="bug" class="table_error"><span class="error_text_min"> Данные не верные! </span> <div style="clear:left;"></div></div><br>';
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo '<br><div id="bug" class="table_error"><span class="error_text_min"> Вы ввели не все данные!</span> <div style="clear:left;"></div></div><br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Код ужасен. Куки точно недоступны и после перезагрузки страницы? Да и хидер неплохо выводить уже в этих ваших else-if-ах. Не надо пихать его в самом начале файла.

Comment: Нет не доступны

Comment: Хидер перед echo поставили?